# How to get the result in JSON format from google?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have tried to query google using my script but my request is going to Google.com page.

What I am looking for is how I can request google for result and out the result on my test html in json format. Here is what I tried:

```html
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function google()
{
var str=document.getElementById('googlebox').value;
str="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=" + str + "&aq=f&oq=&aqi=";
var replaced=str.replace(" ","+");
window.location.replace(replaced)
}
</script>
<input type="text" value="Google" id="googlebox"/>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="google()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement the search box functionality in your web page, if yes then try this "Google Search" option simple and easy. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox

Comment: @BHUVANESHMOHANKUMAR  but I do not intent to use Google API as it has some limitations

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

For any given a URL, a server returns what it returns.

You can't make a server return data in an arbitrary format (or force it to use CORS to grant permission to your script to read that data).

Comment: Is there a way to scrape with javascript? only top 10 result?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into google's custom search API. It has an option to return data in JSON format.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest